# How to open Modal Dialog from ag-grid cell click Angular 6

Tags: angular-material, angular6, ag-grid

Wants to open a mat-dialog on click of Detail Icon. But the issue is `this` is not referring to class. Its referring to the current grid.

```js
    constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

    ngOnInit() {
     this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
     rowSelection: 'multiple',
     floatingFilter: true
    };

    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
      { 
        headerName: 'Detail', field: '', filter: false, width: 80,
        sortable: false,
        onCellClicked: this.openModal,
        cellRenderer: (data) => {
          return `<mat-icon class="mat-icon material-icons" style="cursor:pointer;" aria-hidden="true">
          keyboard_capslock</mat-icon>`;
        }
     },
     { headerName: 'Field Name', field: 'fieldName'}
    ];    

    openModal(row): void {
       const detailRef = this.dialog.open(DetailComponent, {
         height: '100vw',
         width: '80vh',
         direction: 'ltr',
         data: {
          record: row.data
         }
     });
```

```
Error: Unable to get property 'open' of undefined or null reference
```

Here this is referring to Grid and not to the class.

How can I refer to the class method to open the dialog?

Comment: used context: { parentComponent : this} with cellClicked